# How to pass a more variable with page/subpage in Wordprees URL?

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, urls

**mydomain/how-we-work/our-process/**

here is-

**parent page**->how-we-work

sub page->our-process

Now i want to pass a more value by using url.

Answer (score 0):

```
function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){ 
$vars[] = "q"; 
return $vars; 
} 
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );
```

mydomain/how-we-work/our-process/?q=more-value

You can handle it with

```
get_query_var( 'q' );
```

**Edit1:**
If you want to use with 'SEO URL' you need to add_rewrite_rule
    function add_rewrites(){
        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^how-we-work/our-process/([^/]*)/?',
            'index.php?pagename=how-we-work/our-process&q=$matches[2]',
            'top'
        );
       }
      add_action( 'init', 'add_rewrites' );

Comment: Thanks @Abuzer Killiback , But i want : **mydomain/how-we-work/our-process/more-value**

Comment: Ok. Let me help you. What are how-we-work and our-process ? Are they post type or category name or page name or post name? Another point, do you want just for that page how-we-work/our-porcess'?

Comment: i want extra variable with all the sub-page under how-we-work parent page @AbuzerKillibacak

Comment: I edited my answer.